# Woher kommt das Wort "Blümpen" und was bedeutet es?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Es gibt in der [Dresdner Heide](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresdner_Heide) einen "Blümpenweg" (kann man sich zum Beispiel auf [Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23524275) anschauen) und auch eine Region in der Nähe, die auf Wanderkarten als "Die Blümpen" eingetragen ist.
Weiß jemand, was dieses Wort bedeutet, wo es herkommt und warum ein Teil eines Waldes so genannt wurde?

Comment: Der Weg wird wahrscheinlich nach der "Region in der Nähe" benannt sein. Nicht bei allen Ortsnamen ist die Herkunft des Namens heute noch bekannt (Beispiel: "liver" in "Liverpool" - s. Wikipedia).

Comment: @MartinRosenau Die Beziehung zu der "Region in der Nähe" war mir bewusst (ist sie in der Frage nicht deutlich geworden?). Ich hatte gehofft, dass das Wort "Blümpen" ursprünglich einmal im deutschen Wortschatz vorhanden war.

Comment: Also, das Teutsch-Englische Lexicon von 1745 (aus Dresden) kennt immerhin das Verb "blümpen" in der Bedeutung von "sich klümpern", gerinnen und klumpen, bzw. ausflocken wie Milch oder Blut. https://books.google.de/books?id=SJFNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1037&lpg=PA1037&dq=bl%C3%BCmpen&source=bl&ots=hiTbBxl33t&sig=lSgHar-p3eshxwkksGJ-Z1eqbuU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiouaKEipTVAhWoJcAKHdI_CKAQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=bl%C3%BCmpen&f=false

Comment: @user28953: ich lese im Teutsch-Englische Lexicon von 1745 *klümpen* und nicht *blümpen*. Das Versagen der Google-Suche sei hier ausnahmsweise verziehen ;-)

Comment: Im Sächsischen wird p zu b. Vielleicht ist es mit plump, plümper usw. verwandt...

Comment: Hat vielleicht auch etwas mit Humpen zu tun. Nachbarwege sind Wörter mit Kanne, Gabel, Küche, Henkel, ...

Comment: Vielleicht ein verballhornter "Blümchenweg"? - Ich rate, einfach mal bei der fraglichen Gemeindeverwaltung (Rathaus) anzurufen. Selbst wenn sie's dort nicht wissen, werden sie vielleicht sagen können, an wen man sich sonst wenden könnte (der örtliche Heimathistoriker, Geschichtslehrer, o.ä.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann das war auch mein Verdacht, Blümchen -> Blümcken -> Blümpen

Comment: Manche alte Orts- oder Flußnamen stammen offenbar aus Zeiten als in der Gegend noch nicht Deutsch gesprochen wurde sondern eine wesentlich ältere europäische Sprache.

Answer (score 2):

Blümpe bzw. Plümpe kommt aus dem Walserdeutschen und bezeichnet eine Kuhglocke.

Quelle: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_von_der_Wunschh%C3%B6hle_bei_Arosa

Comment: Und wie kommt es von da nach Dresden?

Comment: Da bin ich noch am Suchen. Sowie ich genaueres weiß, meld ich mich. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unter "blümpen" habe ich weit und breit nichts gefunden.

Grimm's Wörterbuch kennt das Wort "Plümpel" und eine Verbform "plumpeln" bzw. "plumpen", die in ihrer Bedeutung mehr oder weniger auf das heutige "plumpsen" hinauslaufen. Mit dem Hintergrund, dass die Sachsen ihre Konsonanten gerne "verweichlichen", könnte deine Ortsbezeichnung durchaus daher kommen.

Comment: Interessanter Ansatz, vor allem, weil die auf den Karten die Gegend bei der Blümpen als sumpfig eingezeichnet ist.

Comment: *bolo* oder ähnliches ist eine slavische Wurzel, eben für ein Tümpel. Slavische Ortsnamen sind im Osten nicht selten. Dagegen ist *plumpeln* offensichtlich eine Form von *fallen*, da der Sinn derselbe ist und baltische Vergleiche mit \*p gegeben sind. Unsicher ist allerdings *plumbum* "Blei", woher engl. *plummet*, *plunge* usw. denn man spricht auf deutsch bei vergifteten Wassern nicht selten von Silberseen. ... warum auch immer.